# Good dialogue Recording Software

Tags: recording, software

Hi

I am new to the movie making. I have shot a small film and doing re-recording and finding it very difficult to do. Can anyone please suggest sound/dialouge recording software which I can use to reduce the echo, and edit the sounds.

Thanks,
Naimuddin

Answer (score 1):

You can always try the free Audacity, or the amazingly cheap Cockos Reaper! I suggest the latter. Free full test, unlimited in time. Prices of Reaper:
$225: full commercial license.
$60:  discounted license.

http://audacity.sourceforge.net/

http://www.reaper.fm/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to really reduce much echo.  That should be taken care of while recording, not after.

Like @Mister Ve said, : Reaper is inexpensive and comes with an abundance of quality plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Reducing echo is not impossible, but it's quite new technological thing (as a plugin for audio use), there's actually one plugin which does it pretty good with some deconvolution algorithm, but it's not classical workflow.

What you should consider and what would be usually done is just recording ADR (automatic dialogue replacement), which is process of recording and replacing bad dialogue lines - distorted, with to much reverb or noise.

If reverb or echo is not so big using a smooth expander might help to keep longer tails of reverb on lower level.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to reduce echo that is in a recording you have already made? If so, you can have a look at these plugins that can be of help:

http://www.zynaptiq.com/unveil/

http://spl.info/produkte/analog-coder-plug-ins/microplugs/de-verb.html

These both run as plugins so will need to be hosted in a DAW software (or audio editor that features plugin support). A DAW can also be a solution for editing your audio.

Many, many upcoming filmmakers overlook the importance of audio. If it is something that really interests you, then why not take on the challenge of editing and mixing. But you should be aware that there is a lot of skill involved and it's not something that can be learned overnight.

The best is to have the cleanest possible audio to work with in the first place. However, if you do have poorly recorded dialogue you may also need to consider re-recording the dialogue (ADR).

As for which software to use, just type "audio editor" or "DAW" in the search field of this site and you'll find plenty of useful tips.